# Methodologies behind shocking a composite index instrument, what assumption distinguishes these?

Tags: risk-management, pricing

Suppose I have a composite index (rebalancing or non-rebalancing) that at present time has some base value $B_{\text{base}}$ in some base economy. I am in the process of shocking the economy on which my composite index is defined ( *changing the index values by different factors*) and re-valuating its base value. I went to code the pricing engine for my composite index after shocking and figured the new value should be calculated as 
$$ 
B_{\text{shocked}} = B_{\text{base}} \cdot \frac{\sum{\big(\text{index weight}}_{i} \cdot \text{shocked index value}_{i}\big)}{\sum{\big(\text{index weight}}_{i} \cdot \text{base index value}_{i}\big)}
$$
But then it occurred to me that were I to only shock certain underlying indices this methodology doesn't quite look correct, and maybe should be
$$
B_{\text{shocked}} = B_{\text{base}} \cdot \sum \bigg(\frac{ \text{shocked index value}_{i}}{\text{base index value}_{i}} \cdot \text{index weight}_{i} \bigg)
$$

My suspicion is that the methodology should depend on how my weights for each underlying index are defined - whether they are set by regressing on a portfolio for instance or otherwise.

I was wondering if anyone could shed any light on which of these two methodologies should be used for what purposes or more importantly what exactly is the assumption that distinguishes them? I'm having a hard time conceptualizing the distinction beyond the fact that they're different mathematical formulas.

Comment: Check the difference between Laspeyres and Paasche Price Index, and the advantages and disadvantages of those.